# Iterate through a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of multidimensional arrays, and need to access each of these arrays and operate on them.
Mock up data:

```
list_of_arrays = map(lambda x: x*np.random.rand(2,2), range(4))
list_of_arrays
[array([[ 0.,  0.],[ 0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.39881669,  0.65894242],[ 0.10857551,   0.53317832]]), array([[ 1.39833735,  0.1097232 ],[ 1.89622798,  1.79167888]]), array([[ 1.98242087,  0.3287465 ],[ 1.2449321 ,  2.27102359]])]
```

**My questions are:**

1- How could I iterate through `list_of_arrays`, so every iteration returns each of the individual arrays?
e.g. iteration 1 returns `list_of_arrays[0]`...last iteration returns `list_of_arrays[-1]`

2- How could I use the result of each iteration as input for another function?

I'm fairly new to Python. My first idea has been to define the function inside a for-loop, but I'm unclear how to implement this:

```
for i in list_of_array:
    def do_something():
```

I was wondering if anybody had a good solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the function elsewhere, then call it within the loop. You don't define the function over and over again within the loop.

```
def do_something(np_array):
    # work on the array here

for i in list_of_array:
    do_something(i)
```

As a working example, lets just say I call the `sum` function on each `array`

```
def total(np_array):
    return sum(np_array)
```

Now I can call it in the `for` loop

```
for i in list_of_arrays:
    print total(i)
```

Output

```
[ 0.  0.]
[ 1.13075762  0.87658186]
[ 2.34610724  0.77485066]
[ 1.08704527  2.59122417]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just access each of the arrays by for loop and then can perform whatever you want

> Examples

Using inbuilt functions

```
import numpy as np
list_of_arrays = map(lambda x: x*np.random.rand(2,2), range(4))
for i in list_of_arrays:
    print sum(i)
```

Using user defined functions

```
import numpy as np
def foo(i):
    #Do something here 

list_of_arrays = map(lambda x: x*np.random.rand(2,2), range(4))
for i in list_of_arrays:
    foo(i)
```

Plotting the data for analysis

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list_of_arrays = map(lambda x: x*np.random.rand(2,100), range(4))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
j=1
for i in list_of_arrays:
    plt.subplot(2,2,j)
    j=j+1
    plt.scatter(i[0],i[1])
    plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

will give you this
[image: Row comparison in 2*100 matrix]